# Reboot takes too long

Tags: reboot

I have a Toshiba S55-B5280 which originally came installed with Windows 10 and after a while I decided to go with linux and try to install it. My choice was Manjaro Linux and so far it has work well however I noted that when I reboot (which is very rare) the system takes too long to do it.

I followed the instructions from [this link](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Debugging/#Shutdown_Completes_Eventually) and the reboot created the shutdown file as expected however I can't understand the real problem here.

I have analyzed the following lines because they seem to be the issue here but I don't know how to fix them.

```
1. [   14.555411] wlp7s0: authenticate with bc:14:01:dc:0c:6b

2. [  731.178646] wlp7s0: deauthenticating from bc:14:01:dc:0c:6b by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)

3. [  821.541959] watchdog watchdog0: watchdog did not stop!
```

Can you guys guide me on this issue?

Below is the last part of the reboot process of the described file:

```
[    3.536977] fuse init (API version 7.23)

[    3.646822] random: nonblocking pool is initialized

[   14.555411] wlp7s0: authenticate with bc:14:01:dc:0c:6b

[   14.562436] wlp7s0: send auth to bc:14:01:dc:0c:6b (try 1/3)

[   14.564434] wlp7s0: authenticated

[   14.566553] wlp7s0: associate with bc:14:01:dc:0c:6b (try 1/3)

[   14.583042] wlp7s0: RX AssocResp from bc:14:01:dc:0c:6b (capab=0x411 
status=0 aid=3)

[   14.584374] wlp7s0: associated

[   14.584404] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp7s0: link becomes ready

[   14.586355] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: US

[   14.586357] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: FCC

[   14.586358] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), 
(max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)

[   14.586360] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 
3000 mBm), (N/A)

[   14.586362] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 1700 mBm), (N/A)

[   14.586363] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2300 mBm), (0 s)

[   14.586364] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2300 mBm), (0 s)

[   14.586365] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 3000 mBm), (N/A)

[   14.586366] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm), (N/A)

[  731.178646] wlp7s0: deauthenticating from bc:14:01:dc:0c:6b by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)

[  731.196240] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:

[  731.196244] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset

[  731.196246] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)

[  731.196249] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)

[  731.196251] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)

[  731.196252] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)

[  731.196255] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)

[  731.196257] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)

[  731.196259] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)

[  731.196261] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)

[  731.196263] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)

[  821.541959] watchdog watchdog0: watchdog did not stop!

[  821.542799] systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...

[  821.684014] systemd-journald[163]: Received SIGTERM from PID 1 (systemd-shutdow).

[  821.764753] systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGKILL to remaining processes...

[  821.766077] systemd-shutdown[1]: Process 1561 (plymouthd) has been been marked to be excluded from killing. It is running from the root file system, and thus likely to block re-mounting of the root file system to read-only. Please consider moving it into an initrd file system instead.

[  821.766159] systemd-shutdown[1]: Hardware watchdog 'iTCO_wdt', version 0

[  821.766259] systemd-shutdown[1]: Unmounting file systems.

[  821.766360] systemd-shutdown[1]: Remounting '/' read-only with options 'discard,data=ordered'.

[  821.790731] EXT4-fs (sda3): re-mounted. Opts: discard,data=ordered

[  821.794716] systemd-shutdown[1]: Remounting '/' read-only with options 'discard,data=ordered'.

[  821.794733] EXT4-fs (sda3): re-mounted. Opts: discard,data=ordered

[  821.794736] systemd-shutdown[1]: All filesystems unmounted.

[  821.794738] systemd-shutdown[1]: Deactivating swaps.

[  821.794764] systemd-shutdown[1]: All swaps deactivated.

[  821.794765] systemd-shutdown[1]: Detaching loop devices.

[  821.795102] systemd-shutdown[1]: All loop devices detached.

[  821.795104] systemd-shutdown[1]: Detaching DM devices.

[  821.795129] systemd-shutdown[1]: All DM devices detached.

[  821.860048] EXT4-fs (sda3): re-mounted. Opts: discard
```

EDIT: I have to mention that my installation is running XFCE4, kernel 4.4.5-1 and systemctl --version shows me:

systemd 229
+PAM -AUDIT -SELINUX -IMA -APPARMOR +SMACK -SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN

I executed journalctl -b -1 to show logs from previous reboot and I found this:

Mar 24 08:40:49 nmiranda-station wpa_supplicant[517]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp7s0 disabled_11b_rates=0

Mar 24 08:40:49 nmiranda-station wpa_supplicant[517]: wlp7s0: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING

Mar 24 08:40:49 nmiranda-station systemd[1](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Debugging/#Shutdown_Completes_Eventually): Stopped WPA supplicant.

**Mar 24 08:42:19 nmiranda-station systemd[1](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Debugging/#Shutdown_Completes_Eventually): session-c2.scope: Stopping timed out. Killing.**

Mar 24 08:42:19 nmiranda-station systemd[1](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Debugging/#Shutdown_Completes_Eventually): Stopped Session c2 of user nmiranda.

Mar 24 08:42:19 nmiranda-station systemd[1](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Debugging/#Shutdown_Completes_Eventually): session-c2.scope: Unit entered failed state.

...

Mar 24 08:42:19 nmiranda-station kernel: watchdog watchdog0: watchdog did not stop!

Mar 24 08:42:19 nmiranda-station systemd-shutdown[1](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Debugging/#Shutdown_Completes_Eventually): Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...

Mar 24 08:42:19 nmiranda-station systemd-journald[163]: Journal stopped

There's an event 'Mar 24 08:42:19 nmiranda-station systemd[1](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Debugging/#Shutdown_Completes_Eventually): session-c2.scope: Stopping timed out. Killing.' that is taking too long.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know a lot about Manjaro but those log files look like they're just the kernel ring buffer which won't report everything that's going on at boot time.  Those messages appear to be from wifi and shouldn't delay bootup.  Take a look at some of the other log files in `/var/log`.

Comment: @mkomarinski Thanks for the reply, I updated the question with more details.

Comment: My systemd is about as bad as Manjaro, but those log entries might give someone else an idea.